# Doctrine remove entity and add a new one instead in one flush

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an unidirectional oneToOne relationship between a Person and User. I am trying to execute method mergePeople.

```
public function mergePeople($personA, $personB)
{
    ...
    $personB->setUser($personA->getUser());
    $personA->setUser(NULL);
    $this->em->remove($personA);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

But this code throws an exception:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE person SET last_name = ?, user_id = ? WHERE id = ?' with params ["Sanchez", 298, 47]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '298' for key 'UNIQ_6F549197A76ED395'
```

I am wondering why I get this error. Is it some kind of bug(in my code or somewhere else) or doctrine doesn't handle this situation normally(should firstly flush setUser(NULL) change and then other changes).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `$this->em->remove($personA)` before calling `$personB->setUser()`.

The EntityManager enqueue all actions done on mapped objects in their execution order.

Also, if you call `$personB->setSomething()` at first, and then you call `EntityManager::flush`, the first statement of the queue (that is `$personB->setSomething()`) will be executed, using the state of the object at the moment of the setter is called.

If you call `$em->remove($personA)` at first, it should be the first executed statement, but you lose the benefit of use the object before remove it.

This is why you should use something like:

```
$user = $personA->getUser();

$personA->setUser(NULL);
$this->em->remove($personA);

$personB->setUser($user);
$this->em->flush();
```

And it should avoid your error about duplicate entry.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure about the queue you speak about. I don't know how doctrine exactly works but here [doctrine api](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html#_getCommitOrder) I can see something that should calculate order of the insertion, deletion and updates.

Your example throws the same error. And imagine that there is the case that you don't want to remove the $personA.

Comment: I tried the example I given you,  and it works on a unique field of the entity (not an association). Can you say me if you use it with a new entry (remove A and insert B) or with an update (remove A and update B) ?